# Correct wiring?

Tags: nodemcu, relay, wires, digital-in

I'm doing some Home automation and am currently trying to automate my intercom system. My overall aim is to be able to detect when someone has pressed the buzzer and then to be able to open the door if I so wish. Below is the diagram of what I intend to do:

[image]

For reference, the buzzer board above is the is the Tegui 1378/1. The documentation can be found (in Spanish) [here](http://www.tegui.es/pdf/manuales-tecnicos/serie-300-400-500-portero/manual-tecnico-portero-convencional-4-n-tegui.pdf). I have been able to conclude the following so far about the pins:

1E: Buzzer

2: Common (12V dc)

3: Door lock

4: Microphone

5: Speaker

However, I have been unable to find any GND on this board. As a result, my diagram above makes use of the GND supplied on the NodeMCU instead; is this okay?

Whilst digging around, I found box in my main fuse box called a [Tegui E-30](http://www.tegui.es/pdf/catalogos/catalogo-S7-tegui.pdf). I believe that this takes in mains and drops it down to 12V for the intercom system. It has two pin outs simply labelled "9" & "10". Now, I am fairly sure that one of these is positive and the other negative; in which case, this would explain where the ground has been but I am unsure. It would be handy to know if it is the case that they are positive and negative respectively as it would be more convenient powering the NodeMCU from the 12V (after dropping it to 5V) rather than getting a massive USB cable from the other room.

I would *really* appreciate any more information people could give me. Both in terms of whether the above diagram would work but also whether someone can have more luck than me finding out exactly what the "9" & "10" pins on the E-30 are.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Kind regards, Rocco

Comment: are you sure it is 12 V  DC? door bells traditionally use 12 V AC to buzzzz

Comment: from the manual "Características: 12 Vac. y 880 mA." see "ac"

Comment: Thanks for your response! I hadn't seen that before; I'd simply done a "Find All" for `12` and had seen a few `12 Vdc` but no `12 Vac` leading me to assume it was DC but I appear to be incorrect. I've just seen that on the E-30 box, it reads `PRIM 230V ~ 50/60Hz 20VA SEC 12V ~ 1A`, I assume the `~` refers to AC, am I correct?

Comment: yes ~ is for AC. I am sure you can find and buy 12 VAC to USB power (5 VDC) adapter to power the NodeMCU.

Comment: I would use a relay to activate the lock and a current sensor or optocoupler to detect current to buzzer. this eliminates the need of common ground

Comment: Thanks for the advice! So would something like [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/FXCO-Supply-Converter-Replace-LM2596S/dp/B07DNFB8HH/ref=sr_1_8?ie=UTF8&qid=1535478106&sr=8-8&keywords=12v+AC+to+5v+DC+Converter) be okay to power the NodeMCU from 12Vac (VIN)? I haven't heard of a current sensor before but that sounds like a great solution, would you be able to recommend a cheap one which would work for this use (I live in the UK)? Also, to confirm, are the "9" & "10" pins on the E-30 positive and negative or both positive? Thanks once again for all your help so far!

Comment: @Juraj For the current sensor, am I correct in saying that it would need to simply give out a Digital output but that the output would have to be 3.3v as the NodeMCU does not accept 5v logic? Also, the current sensors I have seen online have no reference to voltage (that they are detecting) and just refer to AMPS. Why is this and what would I need for this application? Thanks

Comment: current sensor would be analog input. NodeMcu has voltage divider on esp8266 1 V A0 to read to 3.3 V. the optocoupler is simpler. warning, I am not an electronics expert. with AC there is no positive or negative. only 'common' to close the circuit.

Comment: the power supply in the link is for DC input

Comment: Your diagram doesn’t work. You need a GND connection. Looking at the Dutch manual I think 1E isn’t really the buzzer, but the line selector. Each phone unit has a spectate line for 1E but all phones share lines 2-5. My guess is that 1E becomes GND when the number for you phone is pressed at the door. Which explains why you can’t buzz someone in without them ringing the bell first. So I think the relay needs to be between 1E and 3. But I think you just need to get a multimeter and measure the voltages between screw terminals a different states (beep; phone of hook; buzz door; idle).

Comment: found this .... http://www.intercomsrus.com/handset%20pdf/Tegui%20T-71E%20%20Audio%20handset%20Data%20Sheet.pdf